# htaccess redirect with paramater change

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a redirect of pages with different parameter names having the same value such as the below:

Original:  `example.com/trip/trip.php?refID=ZMkZ4rC`

New page:  `example.com/corp/trip/trip.php?id=ZMkZ4rC`

Difference is I am adding `/corp/` and the parameter is changing to `id=`

Using the below I get a redirect but with no parameter being passed.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)refID\=(.*)($|&)
RewriteRule ^trip/trip\.php$ /corp/trip/trip.php?id=$1 [L,R=301]
```

Result:  `example.com/corp/trip/trip.php?id=`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below, as you can see I've used separate rewritecond for uri and query_string.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/trip/trip.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^refID=(.+)
RewriteRule ^ /corp%{REQUEST_URI}?id=%1 [R=301]
```